# Enable anti-aliasing of code view in XCode

Tags: xcode

Is there any way to get XCode to render text in the editor with anti-aliasing enabled? I can't see anything in the preferences dialog that would do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default code font in Xcode and Terminal is 10-point Monaco, which is traditionally *not* anti-aliased because there are hand-tuned bitmaps for this.

You can use the Fonts & Colors pane in the Xcode Preferences to have Xcode use whatever fonts, sizes and colors you prefer.  For example, you could use 11-point Monaco or larger if you want anti-aliased text, or you could use one of a number of bitmap-only programming fonts at their native sizes if pixel-sharpness matters to you.

Personally, I rather like Courier 12 and Inconsolata 13 for coding.  Courier comes with Mac OS X, while [Inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) is a free monospaced font from [Raph Levien](http://www.levien.com/).

Comment: Thanks! Being a Mac newbie it never occured to me that it depended on the size of the typeface - on Windows you enable cleartype and everything is anti-aliased forevermore.

Comment: It's not just based on the size of the typeface - it's based on both the size and the presence of a tuned bitmap version of the font at that size.

Answer (score 7):

XCode text is already anti-alaised.  Check to make sure the font size is larger than specified in:

System Preferences -> Appearance.

If it is larger than that you can try this command at the command line to edit the application setting for xcode.

```
defaults write com.apple.xcode AppleAntiAliasingThreshold -int <font-size>
defaults write com.apple.xcode AppleSmoothFontsSizeThreshold -int <font-size>
```

Comment: I'm sure it's not anti-aliasing - and this is a fresh MacBook that's had nothing but Xcode loaded onto it so far. I tried your setting with a size of 4 (which is what the system prefs setting has by default) and it made no difference. I'll try posting a screenshot.

Comment: Try increasing your font size.  If that makes it antialaised then there must be some other setting restricting it from doing it.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. Personally I like to disable anti-aliasing because it looks blurry. I set AppleAntiAliasingThreshold to a high value and I get exactly what I want. :)

Answer (score 4):

Just a hint:
To change the font for all categories in xcode click inside the category table, press cmd+a and double click somewhere in the category table.
The changes you apply in the Fonts dialog afterwards are applied to all categories.

Hope this helped

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do to disable font anti-aliasing in Xcode has changed over ther years.

Currently, to turn off font anti-aliasing if you're running Xcode 4.6.x and OS X 10.8.x, run these two commands from a Terminal window:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSFontDefaultScreenFontSubstitutionEnabled -bool YES
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode AppleAntiAliasingThreshold -int 24
```

Comment: It's true as of Xcode 6.1 and Yosemite (OS X 10.10) as well.