# Disable Xcode anti-aliasing text inside the code editor?

Tags: xcode, fonts, xcode5, xcode6

When using Xcode, there doesn't seem to be a way to set code editor fonts to be sharp (i.e. with no 'font smoothing). Despite what you might see in the preview area of Preferences > Fonts & Colors, inside the actual code view it’s always smoothed/anti-aliased.

There are some [older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404171/enable-anti-aliasing-of-code-view-in-xcode) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268931/appleantialiasingthreshold-doesnt-work-so-how-to-disable-antialiasing) that address previous versions of Xcode. They suggest changing various settings using `defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode <etc>`, but these do not seem to affect the code view for me in Xcode 5 on Mac OS X 10.8.5. I am using a dual-display setup with one Retina and one non-Retina screen.

I've tried turning off the font smoothing checkbox in System Preferences > General > "Use LCD font smoothing where available", but that only affects sub pixel rendering...

Update (2014-11-25): The problem still occurs with Mac OS X 10.10.1 and Xcode 6.1.1. Here is a screenshot showing the editor view (smoothed) and preferences window (unsmoothed) after using these Terminal commands:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSFontDefaultScreenFontSubstitutionEnabled -bool YES
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 16
```

[image: Xcode]

Comment: added an answer for Xcode 6 & Yosemite.

Comment: can you put a link to the original uncompressed, unscaled screenshot? It's not that I don't believe you, it's just that because SO has scaled the image it's actually applied anti-aliasing onto all the pixels so you can't really see the difference!

Comment: It looks to me like SO has the original image. You can open it in a new browser window.

Comment: Did you try a configuration like mine with one Retina and one non-Retina display? It works fine for me with just the non-Retina display.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't, I don't have a Retina display.

Comment: @MichaelTsai. I wanted share your answer about the xcode plugin with a collegue and when he opened the page your answer was gone... May I know why you removed that answer? and how come is it even possible to delete an answer that was rewarded a bounty?

Comment: @IssamT. It says that moderator Bill the Lizard deleted it. No specific reason was given. Seems strange to me to delete a partial answer that could lead to a solution and leave two answers that definitely don't work.

Comment: @MichaelTsai thats very weird. thanks anyway.

Comment: Some fonts don't allow AA to be switched off. Menlo for example seems to be the default but always has AA, no matter what you configure. Monaco OTOH allows non-AA rendering and therefore also respects the `defaults` lines others have provided. In the Terminal, you can even see which fonts allow AA and which don't: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110764

Comment: @Christian As noted above, the `defaults` command does *not* work for Monaco if you have Retina Mac with a non-Retina external display.

Comment: @MichaelTsai I don't have an Apple laptop at all so it's apparently disabled for other machine types as well. Making this machine-dependent is quite the bold move anyway but ok, I'm not gonna rant.

Comment: any solution for Xcode 9?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Xcode9.3, text anti-aliasing can be disabled in the source editor by  running the following command and restart Xcode:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode SourceEditorDisableAntialiasing -bool YES
```

To turn anti-aliasing on again -

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode SourceEditorDisableAntialiasing -bool NO
```

Comment: I confirm on High Sierra + Xcode 9.4.1 (restart Xcode needed)

Comment: @Trevor Thanks, Updated :)

Comment: not working in mojave, works on high siera with Xcode 10

Comment: @АндрейПервушин - just checked on Mojave and Xcode 10 - WORKSFORME

Comment: Mojave 10.14.2 Mac book air 2014 Mac mini 2014 still not. I have open bug report which is duplicated by some other. "Disable font antialiasing not work anymore" status is [open]. So i assume the issue still exist

Comment: works in xcode 10.3 and mac os mojave 10.14.6. makes text look a lot crisper on a retina display.

Comment: xcode 11.3.1, mojave 10.14.6 - it doesn't work for me. Honestly, it is so f***ng frustrating!!!

Answer (score 7):

If you use a non-retina display, try

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSFontDefaultScreenFontSubstitutionEnabled -bool YES
```

and restart XCode.

**UPDATE:**

Also invoke this:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 24
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that doesn't work with my mixed-resolution dual-display setup.

Comment: Thanks; you are my hero!  Works great in Xcode 5 with Mavericks on Mac Pro.

Comment: Doesn't work on my MacBook Pro 2012 (non-Retina) with Xcode 5.0.2 and OS X 10.9.1

Comment: Works on non-retina display Dell P2416D (2560x1440), Xcode 7.3 on OS X 10.11 El Capitan.

Answer (score 7):

[Mike](https://twitter.com/mikeash/status/565588257019543552) [Ash](https://twitter.com/mikeash/status/565661622702972929) says that he was able to build an Xcode plug-in to tell the text view to use screen fonts. It looks like this would be straightforward to do, although I have not tried it yet.

The general strategy would be (from his tweet) would be to "patch `-[NSTextView drawRect:]` and do `[[self layoutManager] setUsesScreenFonts: YES];`."

Update (2015-08-14): Here is an explanatory [blog post](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-08-14-an-xcode-plugin-for-unsmoothed-text.html) from Ash and the [Xcode project](https://github.com/mikeash/DemoXcodePlugin) for his plug-in. It works for me with Xcode 6.4 if I add `7FDF5C7A-131F-4ABB-9EDC-8C5F8F0B8A90` to the `DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs`. I consider this problem solved!

Update (2016-06-20): As of [Xcode 8](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2016/06/20/disabling-xcode-8-font-smoothing/), you cannot use Xcode plug-ins, but this user default works:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSFontDefaultScreenFontSubstitutionEnabled -bool YES
```

Comment: Thanks. You win my bounty ;-) Let's hope he makes a publication showing us how to use it. Also, please if you manage to fix your xcode by any mean, keep us posted by editing your answer. I will do the same if I figure it out before you do.

Comment: I can confirm this works for XCode 7 as well. 0420B86A-AA43-4792-9ED0-6FE0F2B16A13 is the new uuid for xcode 7.

Comment: In 7.1 it is 7265231C-39B4-402C-89E1-16167C4CC990. Had to recompile the plugin.

Comment: I am not able to get this to work with Xcode 7.2. I am adding the correct UUID to the DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs array but still,even after rebuilding the project and manually adding the plugin to the correct folder, nothing happens when I restart Xcode. Any idea of what am I missing?

Comment: Works for me on Xcode 7.2 without modification. As of `c57e1` it should no longer be necessary to manually supply `DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs`. (Now handled by the `PBXSourcesBuildPhase` section in `project.pbxproj`.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about prior versions, but with Xcode 6.1 and Yosemite (OS X 10.10) two commands are actually required to disable anti-aliasing locally in Xcode.

First, as has already been stated, you need to enter the following at a terminal console:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSFontDefaultScreenFontSubstitutionEnabled -bool YES
```

Then, secondly:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode AppleAntiAliasingThreshold <some integer value>
```

This is preferable to disabling font smoothing or antialiasing throughout the entire operating system. 
It should really be an option to check/uncheck inside the program itself, but at least this works.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, however this did not work for me. I have the font set to Monaco 9. These commands make the font look the way I want within Xcode's font preferences, but they do not seem to affect the main text editor view.

Comment: @MichaelTsai hi Michael, can you give me some more info? What's your current config? Are you now using Xcode 6.1 and Yosemite, or are you still using the same config as in your question? Can you give me a screenshot (by pressing Cmd-Shift-3 on the keyboard) while in Xcode showing the Fonts & Colors window in the foreground and the editor behind it, just so I can see what you are saying? Don't compress it, just upload the screenshot directly.

Comment: I have updated the question with this additional information.