# Forced font antialiasing in Terminal.app on OSX Mavericks (retina display)

Tags: fonts, retina-display, osx-mavericks

Ever since upgrading to 10.9 on my Retina MBP, the "Antialias text" option in Terminal no longer has any effect--all fonts are antialiased at any size. Does anybody know of a way to override this behavior?

I see there's a similar issue/fix for Xcode ([Disable Xcode anti-aliasing text inside the code editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035411/how-can-i-disable-anti-aliasing-in-xcode-5s-code-view)), but a naive attempt to write that value to com.apple.Terminal didn't change anything.

It is perhaps worth noting that I don't see this behavior on my Mac Pro desktop (connected to Dell displays). A friend with a Retina MBP confirmed he's seeing the same behavior.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple software and hardware it should be on AskDifferent or SuperUser

Comment: Fair enough, I'll ask there, but it doesn't seem to be too different than the question I linked to.

Comment: True but Xcode is a development tool whilst Terminal isn't